# Adding the header file folder path in a CMake file

Tags: c++, cmake

I am using CMake in my project and build tree structure is like this
tree view of my system:

```
tree
.
├─ src
├── CMakeLists.txt
├─ CMakeLists.txt
```

I have .cpp and .h that both are present in the `src` folder. So while updating the project structure, the new folder structure is this:

```
tree
.
├─ src
├── CMakeLists.txt
├─ inc
├── headers
├─── file.h
├─ CMakeLists.txt
```

Now I moved the header files to the `inc` folder and updated the CMakeLists.txt as below:

```
include_directories(../inc)
set(HEADERS  ../inc/headerfilename)

add_library(
            libraryName OBJECT
            ${HEADERS}
            application.cpp )


 target_include_directories(libraryName
                            PUBLIC
                            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../inc
                           )
```

Now while running CMake I am getting compilation error as:

```
interrupt.h: No such file or directory
#include "interrupt.h"
```

What could the problem be?

Edit:
The top-level CMakeLists.txt file contains the following lines.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

Comment: Can you try printing the full path? Add this line at the end:

`message(Info "Path is ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../inc")`.

And just to make sure nothing stupid is going on, did you check if you cleaned the CMake cache?

Comment: Check the path with `make VERBOSE=1`.

Comment: yes, I cleared the cache and I added the above lines in the CMakeLists.txt it's printing as ```InfoPath is /home/MathFunctions/src/../inc```.So I added ```include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../inc)```

Comment: It would be better to move the CMakeLists.txt one level up. This does not mean that there is no other solution but it is easier to work with.

Comment: @ Th. Thielemann: Actually I missed adding the CMakeLists.txt in the question. I updated the question. There is CMakeLists.txt one level up already.

Comment: But `add_library` is still in `src/CMakeLists.txt`. This is a topic to be reviewed. In case you move it one level up to, it should be easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of [`CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR.html), which points to the root of your CMake source tree. Then, use [`target_include_directories()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html#command:target_include_directories) to add each include directory for your target. Here is your updated `src/CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
add_library(libraryName OBJECT
            application.cpp
            )

 target_include_directories(libraryName
                            PUBLIC
                            ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/inc
                            ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/inc/folder1
                            ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/inc/folder2
                            ...
                            )
```

Note: Adding the headers in `add_library()` (with your `HEADERS` variable) is only necessary if you want them to appear with the rest of your sources in an IDE. This step should not be necessary for successful compilation.

Comment: Corresponds to the modern cmake practices, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Change your top level `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)
include_directories(inc)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

Comment: I understood the issue, actually there is one extra folder inside the inc folder it's causing the problem now I added that folder also in the include_directories.But is there any solution to add all directories inside inc recursively?

Answer (score 2):

Changed top level CMakeLists.txt as

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)
include_directories(inc/headers)
add_subdirectory(src)
```